# How to retrieve all leads using lightning components?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, leads

I am trying display all contacts using lightning components. but i don't know How to retrieve all leads using lightning components? can you please give me any examples

### Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="GetLeadRecords" >
    <aura:attribute name="reg" type="Lead[]"/>
    <ui:button label="GetLeadRecords" press="{!c.myAction}"/>
    <aura:iteration var="r" items="{!v.reg}" >
    <p>{!r.name}</p>
    <p>{!r.Status}</p>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

### Apex class:

```
    global with sharing class GetLeadRecords {
    @auraEnabled
    public static List<Lead> GetLeads()
    {
     List<Lead> reg=new LIST<Lead>();  
        reg=[select id,name,Status from Lead];

        return reg; 
    } 
    public Lead getSelectedregistrations(Id id)
    {    
      Lead  reg=[select id,name,Status from Lead where id=:id];
        return reg;
    } 

}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Martin Lezer, i tried  the display all contacts it is working fine. can you pls give me any example to display lead records.

Comment: @mallikartest What have to tried to display lead records and where you are facing the issue?

Comment: @ Ajay Prakash Dubey, pls check just now i share the code

Comment: @mallikartest you controller name "GetLeadRecords" does not match with the class name "LeadController".

Comment: @ Ajay Prakash Dubey, sorry for the wrong post. now i edit the code pls check

Comment: @mallikartest What are you trying to achieve from "getSelectedregistrations" method. If you want to get specific lead record the you need to pass the LeadId from the javascript controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component -

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="GetLeadRecords" >
<aura:attribute name="reg" type="Lead[]"/>
<ui:button label="GetLeadRecords" press="{!c.myAction}"/>
<aura:iteration var="r" items="{!v.reg}" >
<p>{!r.FirstName}</p>
<p>{!r.Status}</p>
</aura:iteration>
```

Javascript controller -

```
({
myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.GetLeads");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.reg",response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
}})
```

Apex Controller -

```
  global with sharing class GetLeadRecords {
    @auraEnabled
    public static List<Lead> GetLeads()
    {
        List<Lead> reg=new LIST<Lead>();  
        reg=[select id,FirstName,Status from Lead];

        return reg; 
    } 
    public Lead getSelectedregistrations(Id id)
    {    
        Lead  reg=[select id,name,Status from Lead where id=:id];
        return reg;
    }   
}
```

Comment: @mallikartest Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well..

**1.** When you query on lead object, you will get a List of Leads(not any list). So in your class, you should write

```
List<Lead> leadList =[select id,name,Status from Lead LIMIT 10];
```

or in your way, it should be:

```
List<Lead> leadList =new List<Lead>(); //Creating empty lead list
leadList = [select id,name,Status from Lead LIMIT 10]; // assigning queried values.
```

**2.** Same with the return type of Class. it should be `List<Lead>`.

**3.** In VF pages, we can *pin* the controller and call a method. But in lightning, components can talk only to JS controller, and from there we have to call server side actions as described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm)

Finally, you should be writing something like this to make it work.

**Markup**

```
<aura:component controller="GetLeadRecords" >
    <aura:attribute name="reg" type="Lead[]"/> <!-- Type can be a more generic: type='object[]'-->
    <ui:button label="GetLeadRecords" press="{!c.myAction}"/>
    <aura:iteration var="r" items="{!v.reg}" >
    <p>{!r.name}</p>
    <p>{!r.Status}</p>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller(JavaScript)**

```
myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('calling getLeads');
    var action = component.get("c.getLeads");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            // parsing the JSON string (of leads) we sent from Server side controller.
            var leadObjectList = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
            component.set('v.reg',leadObjectList);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

**Server side controller**

```
global with sharing class GetLeadRecords {
    @auraEnabled public static String getLeads() { 
        List<Lead> leadList =[select id,name,Status from Lead LIMIT 10];
        return JSON.serialize(leadList); // So that we will get  a nice JSON back. 
    }
}
```

Still have doubts? Please let me know.